# How can I use react Component in vue app?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, components

is it possible to use react component in vue 2.4 app in way that react package is not installed in vue app an I will be able to pass props from vue to react component or run methods in react component or emit events from it?

Answer (score 0):

you can have running react application and using `Module Federation` you can embedd any component from this application in your vue app

some examples:
https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples

Answer (score -4):

**The preferred way to use React inside of a Vue app is to use a Vue plugin. Now, use your React components as you would normally use your Vue components!**